# Magento 2: Use Magento\Sales\Model\Order after order has been placed

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I'm currently working on a custom module. I need to get order data of the order that has just been placed. The problem is, that I cannot get the data with `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`. It looks like the event is triggered too soon to use the Order Model. I've tried a couple of events but none seem to work. Does anyone know a solution that will work? It may be a different event, an alternative for the Order Model, or any fixes in the code.

> Observer:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderExport implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_logger;

    protected $orderModel;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Order $orderModel
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
        $orderId = ltrim($orderId, '0');
        $orderId = (int)$orderId;

        $this->_logger->info("New order: ".$orderId);

        $this->createXml($orderId);
    }

    public function createXml($orderId) {
        $this->orderModel->load($orderId);
        $orderModel = $this->orderModel;

        // It breaks on this:
        $customerName = $orderModel->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    }
}
```

> Events:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="order_export" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderExport" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the approach of getting the order id from the increment id you are using in your code can't really work. If you have an increment id of an order you can load the order by increment id (method `loadByIncrementId`). But anyway that's only possible after the order has been saved to database, which is not the case in the event you are using.

If you need the order id (the value of the entity_id, primary key in `sales_order` table) for whatever reason, I would suggest to use a later event, for example `checkout_submit_all_after` (or `sales_order_save_after`).

If you use one of those events you should have the complete order object in the observer and wouldn't need to load the order again.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! It looks like that does the trick. However, I have one question: Do you know how to get the Shipping Address? I used the `getShippingAddress()` function from the Order Model. However, the `getShippingAddress()` function doesnt exist in in the order object in the observer. The same goes for the `getShippingMethod()` function.

Comment: Update: I got it working allready. I figured out the Order Model is usable on the `checkout_submit_all_after` event.